# materializecss and angular app

Tags: angularjs, materialize

I'm trying to build an app in `angularJS` and `materializeCSS`. The page loads, but I have a button that should open a pop-up form and although I tried several times, I can't figure out the problem :(

I've tried with `<a href>` but it's the same problem, I can't see any pop and as well, I don't see any errors in the console

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Products</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/css/materialize.min.css" />

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" />
<style>
.width-30-pct{
    width:30%;
}

.text-align-center{
    text-align:center;
}

.margin-bottom-1em{
    margin-bottom:1em;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="container" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="productsCtrl">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12">
                <h4>Products</h4>
                <!-- used for searching the current list -->
                <input type="text" ng-model="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search product..."/>

    <!-- table that shows product record list -->
            <table class="hoverable bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="text-align-center">ID</th>
                        <th class="width-30-pct">Name</th>
                        <th class="width-30-pct">Description</th>
                        <th class="text-align-center">Price</th>
                        <th class="text-align-center">Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody ng-init="getAll()">
                <tr ng-repeat="d in names | filter:search">
                    <td class="text-align-center">{{ d.id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ d.name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ d.description }}</td>
                    <td class="text-align-center">{{ d.price }}</td>
                    <td>
                        <a ng-click="readOne(d.id)" class="waves-effect waves-light btn margin-bottom-1em"><i class="material-icons left">edit</i>Edit</a>
                        <a ng-click="deleteProduct(d.id)" class="waves-effect waves-light btn margin-bottom-1em"><i class="material-icons left">delete</i>Delete</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

                <!-- floating button for creating product -->
            <div class="fixed-action-btn" style="bottom:45px; right:24px;">
                <!-- <a class="btn-floating btn-large waves-effect waves-light red" href="#modal1" ng-click="showCreateForm()"><i class="material-icons">add</i></a> */-->
                <button data-target="modal1"  class="btn-floating btn-large waves-effect waves-light red" ng-click="showCreateForm()">Add</button>
            </div>
            <!-- modal for for creating new product -->
            <div id="modal1" class="modal">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <h4 id="modal-product-title">Create New Product</h4>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="input-field col s12">
                            <input ng-model="name" type="text" class="validate" id="form-name" placeholder="Type name here..." />
                            <label for="name">Name</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-field col s12">
                            <textarea ng-model="description" type="text" class="validate materialize-textarea" placeholder="Type description here..."></textarea>
                            <label for="description">Description</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-field col s12">
                            <input ng-model="price" type="text" class="validate" id="form-price" placeholder="Type price here..." />
                            <label for="price">Price</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-field col s12">
                            <a id="btn-create-product" class="waves-effect waves-light btn margin-bottom-1em" ng-click="createProduct()"><i class="material-icons left">add</i>Create</a>

                            <a id="btn-update-product" class="waves-effect waves-light btn margin-bottom-1em" ng-click="updateProduct()"><i class="material-icons left">edit</i>Save Changes</a>

                            <a class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-light btn margin-bottom-1em"><i class="material-icons left">close</i>Close</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>




<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.96.1/css/materialize.min.css">

<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.96.1/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<!--angular -->
    <script src="libs/js/angular.min.js"></script>


    <script>
// angular js codes will be here
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('productsCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

     $scope.showCreateForm = function(){
   // clear form
    $scope.clearForm();

    // change modal title
    $('#modal-product-title').text("Create New Product");

    // hide update product button
    $('#btn-update-product').hide();

    // show create product button
    $('#btn-create-product').show();


}

     // clear variable / form values
$scope.clearForm = function(){
    $scope.id = "";
    $scope.name = "";
    $scope.description = "";
    $scope.price = "";
}



    // create new product 
    $scope.createProduct = function(){

    // fields in key-value pairs
    $http.post('create_product.php', {
            'name' : $scope.name, 
            'description' : $scope.description, 
            'price' : $scope.price
        }
    ).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(data);
        // tell the user new product was created
        Materialize.toast(data, 4000);

        // close modal
        $('#modal-product-form').closeModal();

        // clear modal content
        $scope.clearForm();

        // refresh the list
        $scope.getAll();
    });
    }

 });
// jquery codes will be here
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  // the "href" attribute of .modal-trigger must specify the modal ID that wants to be triggered
  $('.modal-trigger').leanModal();
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your showCreateForm function you need to add code to show the modal:

```
$scope.showCreateForm = function(){
  // clear form
  $scope.clearForm();
  // change modal title
  $('#modal-product-title').text("Create New Product");
  // hide update product button
  $('#btn-update-product').hide();
  // show create product button
  $('#btn-create-product').show();
  // show modal
  $('#modal1').show();
}
```

Here it is in Plunker with the above fix:
https://plnkr.co/edit/sUb43sKyBGaIGpBXvcrP?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Try using directives instead of jQuery code in controllers. There are repos that have angular+materilizecss in GitHub

Check : http://krescruz.github.io/angular-materialize/#getting-started

Comment: I'd suggest to elaborate your answer. While the link may be helpful, it is generally recommended to include most imprtant parts of code/explanation directly to your answer. See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer